# How to pass data to a ViewController from push notification through the storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

This is a fragment of my iOS app:

[image]

where the `Tab Bar Controller` is my root controller followed by a `Navigation Controller` followed by a `Table View Controller` followed by a final `View Controller`. When a **push notification** arrives, I need to pass some data to this final view controller (in order to fill those blank `UITextView` and a `UITextField`). 
This is the code I have written up to now but I don't know how to go on:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    //let tab :UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    //tab.selectedViewController = tab.viewControllers![3]
    print("NOTIFICA \n")
    print(userInfo)

    let tab :UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    tab.selectedViewController = tab.viewControllers![2]
}
```

This code is supposed to let me access to the 3-rd view controller of the tab bar controller but I need to go beyond it to the final view controller and pass `userInfo`to it. How shall I do? Thanks to all.

**UPDATE**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    //let tab :UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    //tab.selectedViewController = tab.viewControllers![3]
    print("NOTIFICA \n")
    print(userInfo)
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    application.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MyNotificationReceived", object: userInfo)
}


class DynamicEventsViewController:UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var dynamicEventTitle:UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dynamicEventDescription:UITextView!

var eventTitle:String!
var eventDescription:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icons/bar.png"))
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(DynamicEventsViewController.notificatonArrived(_:)), name: "MyNotificationReceived", object: nil)

    self.dynamicEventTitle.text = self.eventTitle.uppercaseString
    self.dynamicEventDescription.text = self.eventDescription
}

func notificatonArrived(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:[NSObject : AnyObject] = notification.userInfo!
    self.eventTitle = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"] as! String
    self.eventDescription = userInfo["aps"]!["description"] as! String
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

}
```

Comment: get your view controller object from self.storyBoard.instatiateViewController("YourViewController") & then push.

Comment: Should I maybe perform `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)` before?

Comment: You can do that otherwise just write self.storyborad

Comment: I am inside `AppDelegate.swift` and it says it does not have a member called storyboard... :S

Comment: ok get storyboard instance. One more thing you are using TabbbarCntroller. So be careful.

Comment: You can use `NSNotificationCenter`

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I have deleted it, I won't use it anymore.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore what is `NSNotificationCenter`?

Comment: @LoryLory NSNotificationCenter used to pass message from one class to another class. it's a design pattern in iOS.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS: sorry, the last question: how can I push a view controller from app delegate?

Comment: let navController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
         
let myViewController =  storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController")
         navController.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)

You can add & edit your own storyboard identifier for viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two questions to this post.

1. How to take the user to the final view controller upon receiving a push notification?
2. How to pass the payload of the push notification to the final view controller?

For #1, you will have to first determine how the user would normally go to the final view controller. Based on the storyboard he would switch to the third tab, select an item in the table view which would then load the final view controller. So you will have to do this programatically by switching the Tab controller to the third view controller, then getting the navigation controller and then simulating the selection of an item in the table view which will then load the final view controller.

For #2 notifications may not work properly because the final view controller may not be loaded by the time the notification is sent. Its hard to sync this. In this case you can save the push notification payload in user defaults using `NSStandardUserDefaults`. Then in the final view controller you can check if there is any prefs already stored as a part of this flow and if so load it and populate the text field and text view with the values and delete the prefs so that next time it is loaded the values are not populated.

This kind of decouples the push notification and saving of the data to be preloaded in the final view controller from the actual loading of this data in the final view controller.

Another option is to just load the final view controller as a modal view controller and pass the data to that controller at the time of receiving the notification itself. Of course this is applicable only if your final view controller's data model doesn't require it to always comes from the table view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NSNotificationClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/), you can read a [tutorial here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/). Register the notification in (say) `FinalViewController`

```
class FinalViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(FinalViewController.notificatonArrived(_:)), name: "MyNotificationReceived", object: nil)
  }

  func notificatonArrived(notification: NSNotification) {
    //do you updation of labels here
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
  }

  deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
  }
}
```

And when you receive the notification the do this

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print("NOTIFICA \n")
    print(userInfo)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MyNotificationReceived", object: userInfo)
  }
```

Comment: This is very interesting! I think I am going to do it at once and let you know. As soon as I have made it work I will mark it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Please do read about `NSNotificationCenter` so that you have good understanding of it and then only you can use it properly.

Comment: I am afraid there's something I am missing because when I tap on the notification alert nothing happens...se my updated question

Comment: That's why I told you to read about notification center. If your application has `FinalViewController` at front and you press home, then a notification comes and you tap then you might can watch the magic. Till then read more about it and understand it. If your application doesn't have FVC initiated then the observer is never registered hence no notification will be posted.

Comment: I have read some tutorials but I really do not understand what you mean...they show your same code without saying much more but it does not work...

Comment: All right no problem, I can understand. Until `viewDidLoad` of FVC get called `NSNotificationCenter` cannot post notification. The `addObserver` code must run to receive the notifications. Good luck

Comment: sorry, what do you mean for FVC (F=? View Controller)?

Comment: F means your final view controller